# VS Code Java tests failing with "Failed to load Application Context"

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was using Intellij IDEA for java development then I decided to switch to VS Code due to its usability. But I'm facing the issue when running tests. Every test falls with "Failed to load ApplicationContext" error, however they're properly running in IDEA.

How can I manage it?

Comment: what project is yours?maven or gradle ?

Comment: is the issue solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Test it with gradle/maven in command line. Enter directory where u have gradle.build or pom.xml and run `mvn test` or `./gradlew test`